# Map tag area error in W3C validation

Tags: html, area

On W3C validator my website is getting the following error:

```
Error Line 240, Column 183: Bad value 13.483146067416, 97.752808988764, 586.14232209738, 317.22846441948 for attribute coords on element area: Expected a digit but saw . instead.
…ews/3561" title="Click For zoom" class="iframe squidhead" alt='Parshvabhoomi'> 
Syntax of rectangle:
...
Error Line 242, Column 183: Bad value 11.610486891386, 317.22846441948, 204.11985018727, 523.97003745318 for attribute coords on element area: Expected a digit but saw . instead.
…ews/3562" title="Click For zoom" class="iframe squidhead" alt='Parshvabhoomi'>
```

How can I fix that?

Comment: And we should guess at what code you have that causes this?

Comment: You can't use floating-point coordinates. Consider rounding them.

Comment: i have already round using php round function.but still this not resolved

Comment: http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.parshvabhoomi.com%2F&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0

Comment: Per HTML spec you also can't use spaces to separate them, just commas: https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/infrastructure.html#valid-list-of-integers

Answer (score 0):

Per HTML spec, you can use only integers with just a comma separating them on the `coords` attribute: https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/infrastructure.html#valid-list-of-integers

So you have to round the floating-point values and remove the spaces between them.

Comment: thank you paulo freitas but i have round the coords value

Comment: @user3122883 Do you also removed the spaces/dots? Take for example the first error line: "13.483146067416, 97.752808988764, 586.14232209738, 317.22846441948". You should have used the `coords="13,98,586,317"` attribute in this case, for instance.